# How to divide data extracted from table cells using Xpath?

Tags: html, parsing, xpath

I have this html table:

```
<table class="info">
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="name">Year</td><td>2011</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Storey</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Area</td><td>170</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Condition</td><td>Renovated</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Bathroom</td><td>2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In this table data is organized in such way that each row contains 2 cells enclosed in `<td>` tags. First cell contains information about data type. For example year of building of house. Second cell contains year information itself which is 2011.

I want to extract data in such way that data type and information are divided and corresponded to each other. I want to extract data type and information this way:

```
Year: 2011
Storey: 3
Area: 170
Condition: Renovated
Bathroom: 2
```

I want to get each row and two cells being able to access separately so I could put them in excel table and put data type in 1 column and information to 2nd column.

For now I have this Xpath code:

```
//table[@class="info"]//tr//td/text()
```

It returns information in single flow in this exact format:

```
Year
2015
Storey
3
Area
170
Condition
Renovated
```

I want to extract rows and cells correspondingly so I can put them in excel:

```
Year (1st excel column): 2011 (2nd excel column)
Storey (1st excel column): 3 (2nd excel column)
```

How to do it using Xpath?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that using xpath only. How do you execute the xpath? (through XSLT/XQuery/some kind of programming language), and what is the xpath version? (1/2/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
//tr/join(td/text(),": ")
```

This would probably return what you need.

`text()` might be optional depending on the tool you're using.
When you use [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) it's optional. See [this demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctable%20class%3D%22info%22%3E%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22name%22%3EYear%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E2011%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22name%22%3EStorey%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E3%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22name%22%3EArea%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E170%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22name%22%3ECondition%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3ERenovated%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22name%22%3EBathroom%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E2%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Ftr%2Fjoin(td%2C%22%3A%20%22)%2C%0A%22%22%2C%0A%2F%2Ftr%2Fjoin(td%2Ftext()%2C%22%3A%20%22)&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).